# Iterating through table looking for select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that I am populating dynamically through a ajax function.

```
            <!-- Tab4 -->
        <div id="ServiceOrderTasks" class="tab-pane">
          <div class="widget white-full">
            <div class="widget-body">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <!-- BEGIN COLUMN -->
                <div class="span12">
                  <!--BEGIN LABEL & BADGE PORTLET-->
                  <table id="tasktable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Service Order Task</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="taskTableContents">

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <!--END LABEL & BADGE PORTLET-->
                </div>
                <!-- END COLUMN -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The ajax code writes the contents

```
function GetServiceOrderDetailsOnComplete4(result) {
var content = "";

  $('#taskTableContents > tbody').empty(); 

  var records = result.split("*");
  var len = records.length - 1; 
  var id_name = "";
  var field = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    var record = records[i].split("|");
    id_name = "";
    id_name = "taskID|" + record[0] + "|" + record[1];

    field = record[38].trim();
    if (field == "1") {
      content = content + "<tr><td colspan='2'>" + record[2] + "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      "  <select name='" + id_name + "' id='" + id_name + "' data-role='slider' data-mini='true'>";

  switch (record[14]) {
  case "0":
    content = content + "    <option value=1>Completed</option>" +
      "    <option value=0 selected>Incomplete</option>" +
      "    <option value=0>Not Applicable</option>";
    break;

  case "1":
    content = content + "    <option value=1 selected>Completed</option>" +
      "    <option value=0>Incomplete</option>" +
      "    <option value=0>Not Applicable</option>";
    break;
  case "2":
    content = content + "    <option value=1>Completed</option>" +
      "    <option value=0>Incomplete</option>" +
      "    <option value=0 selected>Not Applicable</option>";
    break;

  default:
    content = content + "    <option value=1>Completed</option>" +
      "    <option value=0 selected>Incomplete</option>" +
      "    <option value=0>Not Applicable</option>";

    break;

  }


  content = content + "  </select>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>";
    };
  };
  $("#taskTableContents").append(content);
}

function GetServiceOrderDetailsOnFail(result) {
}
```

Although pretty messy, the code above works.

Here is the question:  I need to iterate through the table and get each of the rows.

There is some conditional code that sets a flag based on the selected value.

```
  //  $('#tasktable > tbody  > tr > td > select').each(function () {
  $('#taskTableContents > tbody  > tr > td > select').each(function () {
    var parms = this.id.split("|");
    var sor = parms[1];
    var seq = parms[2];
    var v = $(this).val();   // will get the value correctly
    switch (v) {
      case "0":
//        UpdateServiceOrderDetailStatus(sor, seq, 0);
      okToClose = false;
      break;
      case "1":
        UpdateServiceOrderDetailStatus(sor, seq, 1);
      break;
      case "2":
//        UpdateServiceOrderDetailStatus(sor, seq, 0);
      okToClose = false;
      break;
    }
  });
```

During execution of the code, 
The debugger gets to this line and jumps directly to the okToClose = false line.

```
  $('#taskTableContents > tbody  > tr > td > select').each(function () {
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When do you run the code that searches the table? Is it in an event handler?

Comment: yes - it is executed when the users presses a button

Comment: Your loop will set `okToClose = false` if **any** of the dropdowns are set to `0` or `2`.

Comment: BTW, I don't see `value=2` in any of the options. You have `value=0` for both `Incomplete` and `Not Applicable`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to parse a dynamically table with..

```
#taskTableContents > tbody  > tr > td > select
```

Which referes to a very specific element, I would add a class on your selector and then iterate through each selector in the document until you can find the one you want. That way you don't even need to worry about the table layout.

```
<select class="select"/>
   <options>
</select>
$('.select').each(function() {
   //We have each select now as this
   if(this.id === somethingIWant) {
        //do something with this select
   };
});
```

Hopefully this clears it up for you, if not maybe you can provide another description of what you are trying to actually do or make a jsfiddle of your code not working properly.